# Curve problem in Differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the coordinate functions of the curve $\beta = \alpha(h)$, where $x$ is the curve in $$\alpha (t)= \left( 1+\cos t, \, \sin t, \, 2\sin \frac{t}{2} \right)$$ for all $t$ and $h(s)=\cos^{-1}(s)$ on 
$j:0<s<1$.

This problem is from "Elementary Differential Geometry - Barrett O'Neill". I don't know answer. I need your help. Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The curve shown in blue is called Viviani's curve and is the intersection of a cylinder given by $ (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1 $ and the sphere given by $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 $ . Your curve is the portion of the curve shown in red in the drawing, one segment of the entire curve defined only in the positive octant.

Comment: I don't understand this picture and your answer. what is entire curve?

Comment: Check out this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VivianisCurve.html to see how Viviani's curve relates to the $\alpha$ in your exercise. Since we are reparametrizing the curve we need to check what happens when we do so. Is the range of the red curve equal to the entire curve? ( I have actually exaggerated the extent to which the curve is a portion of the original curve. You should be able to compute the end points of the  reparametrized curve to see that they are now only a portion of the original curve.